# How to get text from TextField in onAction method?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am getting NullPointerException when I am trying to get text from `TextField` in one of my `Button` on action method. This is my textField definition:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPromptText("Some text");
GridPane.setMargin(textField, new Insets(50, 50, 10, 50));
gridPane.add(textField, 0, 0);
```

And this is my button with its on action method:

```
Button button = new Button("Button");       
GridPane.setMargin(button , new Insets(0, 50, 0, 50));
gridPane.add(button , 0, 1);
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        String text = textField.getText();                              
    }
});
```

I am getting `NullPointerExcpetion` in this line: `String text = textField.getText();`. How can I get text from textField in onAction method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you are shadowing your `TextField` in a method or constructor. This appears to be a possibility given that the local variable has not been declared as `final`.
If your `EventHandler` is using a class member variable called `textField`, then replace

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
```

with

```
textField = new TextField();
```